# Convert flow chart / decision tree to interactive pages

Tags: tree, flowchart

I have a flow chart or decision tree that I'd like people to walk through interactively. Basically, every question in the decision tree should be presented to the user and once he makes his choice, he moves on to the next block. Example:

Q1: Are you over 18?
(If Yes, go to Q2, if No, go to Q3)

Q2: Do you own a car?
(If Yes, show some text/send email/etc, if No, go to Q3)

Q3: (Message only) Thanks for trying!

The general survey/questionnaire interfaces I find online do not seem optimized for this use. For example, they require you to make your choice and then press Next. I have the feeling I'm looking in the wrong place but obviously cannot find a better one...

The result of the conversion should be either a portable Windows program, a set of webpages hosted on the internet or I could install some application on a Linux webserver. Because the first question in the envisioned application will guide the user to one of 4 or 5 subtrees, easily being able to enable/disable/edit subtrees separately would be a plus.

Comment: https://www.surveymonkey.com/ might help you, but if not it sounds like you need to contact a web developer.  Afaik there is no off the shelf solution to this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I could code something myself, but I was hoping for a solution that tech-savvy, non-coders could handle themselves. As a non-profit, we'd prefer not to hire someone to build a custom solution.

Comment: Drat. I have the same question. It seems like such an obvious thing that people might want to use (my ideal would be like a multi-path Prezi) but it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score -1):

An ATM allows a customer to withdraw a maximum of $500 per day. If a customer withdraws more than $300, the service charge is 4% of the amount over $300. If the customer does not have sufficient money in the account, the ATM informs the customer about the insufficient funds and gives the customer the option to withdraw the money for a service charge of $25.00. If there is no money in the account or if the account balance is negative, the ATM does not allow the customer to withdraw any money. If the amount to be withdrawn is greater than $500, the ATM informs the customer about the maximum amount that can be withdrawn. Write an algorithm that allows the customer to enter the amount to be withdrawn. The algorithm then checks the total amount in the account, dispenses the money to the customer, and debits the account by the amount withdrawn and the service charges, if any.

Comment: What question are you answering?